# How to use collate option with rails3 migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations, collate

I am using Sqlite3 which comes default with rails 3.
How to change a particular column to `collate NOCASE` with a rails migration?

I tried out `t.change :name, :string, :collate => "NOCASE"`, but the case insensitive search for `find_by_name("test", :order => "name collate NOCASE")` gives no result as expected?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the format might be the issue. Try:

```
:COLLATE => :NOCASE
```